# How to cleanly break links in Excel VBA 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to programmatically break all links, then recreate them in a workbook.

I got some VBA code to cleanly break Excel links in Excel 2010, however the trouble I always have is that Excel will prompt me every time I RECREATE the link.

Here's what I'm doing:

Here's the BreakLinks procedure :

```
Sub BreakLinks()
    vLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

    ' Break all links in the active workbook.
    For lLink = LBound(vLinks) To UBound(vLinks)
        ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink _
            Name:=vLinks(lLink), _
            Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next lLink
end sub
```

Here's the Main section: 
   *** Please note that the last line where I assign thisFormula is where Excel prompts me with a File Dialog box which forces me to either cancel or choose my Master Workbook I'm linking back to...

```
    BreakLinks    ' call proc to break the links
    thisFormula = "='[DataMaster - Data Template.xlsm]MASTER'!$B" + Trim(Str(myRow))     ' reference back to master workbook
    Range("A1").Formula = thisFormula       ' i.e. "='[DataMaster - Data Template.xlsm]MASTER'!$B32"
    Range("B1").Formula = "=D1"
    Range("C1").Formula = "=E1/100"
    thisFormula = "=BDH('[DataMaster - Data Template.xlsm]MASTER'!$A" + Trim(Str(myRow)) + "," + charCode + "PX_LAST" + charCode + ",FirstDate," + charCode + " " + charCode + "," + charCode + "cols=2;rows=50" + charCode + ")"
    Range("D1").Formula = thisFormula
```

I'd like to know how to avoid this very annoying Excel prompt, and just cleanly recreate my Formula/Link.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Application.DisplayAlerts:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'<statements that may invoke alerts>
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: I still have two problems with breakLinks above: 1) if old workbook still exists, it will constantly include the old workbook location in the links (in addition to my newly linked workbook. 2) if the old workbook doesn't exist, I can't break the link at all (apparently since the old source is not found)

Comment: You may want to check if the workbook has other links besides within formulas, they can be hidden in named ranges, conditional formatting, or data validation. I have had issues with breaking links that are embedded in those areas but I was always eventually able to find and break them manually.

Comment: thanks Ross. I can break them manually indeed cause I know exactly where my formulas and links are. However, when I trace through my code and add my third formula (i.e. the bloomberg BDH() api call with the Bloomg excel plugin) - my old link comes right back ! Very strange...almost as if something is hard-coded.

Comment: @bob So you are able to break the links, save the workbook, reopen it and the links are still gone?